# Trying to retrieve column header of flexible search thru java

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

Im currently trying to retrieve the column header used in a flexible search using java. However i cannot find any method in hybris to do so.

Here is my method to process the flexible search:

```
private List<List<Object>> processFlexibleQuery(final String flexibleQuery, final List<String> paramValues, final List<String> paramNames, final int headersCount) 
    {
        final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        final FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery(flexibleQuery);
        final Class[] resultTypesArray = new Class[headersCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < headersCount; i++)
        {
            resultTypesArray[i] = String.class;
        }           

        query.setResultClassList(Arrays.asList(resultTypesArray));

        if (paramValues.size() > 0 && paramNames.size() == paramValues.size())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.size(); i++)
            {
                params.put(paramNames.get(i).trim(), paramValues.get(i).trim());
            }
        }

        query.addQueryParameters(params);
        final SearchResult<List<Object>> result = flexibleSearchService.search(query);
        final List<List<Object>> productList = result.getResult();

       return productList;

    }
```

My method work fine. I have looked up a couple of class provided by hybris to put the column header of the flexible search in a list but i cannot find any method.
Basically if i process this FS in my method:

```
SELECT {p.code} as potato,
       {p.name} as name
FROM {product as p}
```

I want to have "potato" and "name" in a list. I dont want to parse directly the query using the "as" because if there is a subquery in the flexible search this will bug out. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality doing by hac already, so there must be solution for it. I haven't got exact solution but I can share tools which are similar functionality. You can check their source code for finding your way.

1. [hybris tools gui chrome extension](https://hybrismart.com/2017/03/13/hybris-flexiblesearch-chrome-extension/)
2. [hybris FlexibleSearch command-line tool](https://hybrismart.com/2016/08/18/hybrisflexiblesearch-command-line-tool-web-api/) [source](https://github.com/raliev/hybristools)

While I am searching urls, I find [exact point](https://github.com/raliev/hybristools/blob/master/src/com/epam/services/FlexibleSearchToolService.java#L115) for you.